# NodeJS - error EPERM when moving file to its parent directory?

Tags: node.js, fs

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291647/move-all-files-in-directory-to-parent-with-node-js) saying to use `mv` module.

But it doesn't seem it works if I want to move file to its parent directory.

For example I want to move all files on `/tmp` to `/`

```
var root = process.cwd(); // the directory where i run the script

mv(root + "/tmp", root, { mkdirp: true }, function(err) {
  if(err) { return logger.error(err); }
});
```

and I got this error:

```
error:  Error: EPERM, rename 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\test\tmp'
```

I think it's because moving in NodeJS uses `rename` workaround and it can't rename it to the parent directory.

Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, used `fs-extra` module [here](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra#movesrc-dest-options-callback).

the `fs.move` actually works